# BCP output file not getting generated

Tags: bcp, ssms-2012

i am running below query in the ssms 2012.

> exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp uctconfiguration.dbo.requirement out D:\requirement.txt -w -T -S "servername"'

Below is the log

> NULL Starting copy... SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error =
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Warning: BCP import with a
>   format file will convert empty strings in delimited columns to NULL.
>   1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 1000
>   1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 2000
>   1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 3000
>   NULL 3148 rows copied. Network packet size (bytes): 4096 Clock Time
>   (ms.) Total     : 297    Average : (10599.33 rows per sec.) NULL

Data is getting copied to the file.But when i go to the location specified in BCP command , i am not able to find the output file

Comment: when you do EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_cmdshell N'dir d:\' do you see the file?

Comment: Its the D:\ from the server's perspective, not the client's

Comment: yes Brad , i am able to see file in logs but i am not able to find directory. Is this saving file from server's perspective ? like @jasper said

Comment: i found the file on server's drive. Thanks for help !

Comment: @G.SAbhaypal I changed my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running commands in `xp_cmdshell` paths are relative to the server